# «Согласно сезона» или «согласно сезону»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, падежи, управление, лексическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно: *согласно сезон**а*** или *согласно сезон**у***?
В родительном или дательном падеже и почему?

Comment: https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/slovar-trudnostey/soglasno#:~:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC,%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%2D%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *согласно сезон**у***.

Справочная служба русского языка «[Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/slovar-trudnostey/soglasno)»:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Всё в природе согласно сезону –

Радость солнца и дождика плач.

Клён надел золотую корону,

Нарядились осины в кумач.*

Андрей Егорьевич («[Стихи.ру](https://stihi.ru/2023/09/22/2023)»)

Comment: Сезон - это временной промежуток, как год или месяц. Но не говорят же "согласно году"?

Comment: @Буратино "согласно году" не говорят, а вот "согласно сезону", оказывается, говорят. Не запретишь. Так пусть говорят по правилу с дательным падежом.

Answer (score 2):

Никак не правильно, по-русски "согласно" употребляют по отношению к источникам речи-письма - договорам, законам, письмам, речам, либо по отношению к персонификациям сил природы и тп., ну или личностям людей. А сезон - это не персонификация, а термин.

Хотя, бывают, выражения в общем виде: согласно срокам. Но "согласно сроку" - нет.

Поэтому сочетание слова "согласно" и слова "сезон" - неудачное.

Лучше использовать "**согласно моде этого сезона**".

Либо ещё проще - "**в сезон**".

Возможно, если речь идёт о неком известном цикле, например, о погодных сезонах, тогда можно употребить во множественно числе: согласно сезонам, по аналогии с "согласно срокам". Но не в единственном числе.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151978/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Что я поняла **из этой темы** (с учетом комментариев)

1. Падеж, конечно **дательный**, но стилистика такого сочетания **некорректна.** Об этом говорит **практика письма**. В Нацкорпусе встретился только один пример, в то время как для сочетания "по сезону" 205 примеров. В **[Карте слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE)** даны такие **варианты:** согласно законам природы, согласно с обстоятельствами дела, согласно легенде, теории, правилам, плану, исследованиям и т.д.

Другими словами, это **официально-деловой** (канцелярский) стиль, что видно и **[по словарю](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42)**:

**СОГЛАСНО.** I. нареч. к 1. Согласный. Жить с. Все свидетели с. показывали что-л. Запеть с. С. кивнуть головой. II. **предлог. кому-чему. Соответственно, сообразно с чем-л., следуя чему-л.** С. законам природы. С. уговору. С. уставу. С. статистическим данным. Займите места с. купленным билетам. Согласно с кем-чем, **в зн. предлога. В соответствии с чем-л.** Поступать согласно с инструкцией.

2. В любом случае предлог ***согласно*** обычно не относится к существительным со значением **времени** (год, месяц, сезон). И если в художественной литературе используется такое сочетание, то оно **метафорично** по своему характеру, да и не очень **художественно**.

   ```
   Всё в природе согласно сезону –
   Радость солнца и дождика плач.
   Клён надел золотую корону,
   Нарядились осины в кумач.
   ```

Можно написать: **согласно с сезоном))**  Тоже криво, но на метафору больше похоже.

Answer (score 0):

Падеж может быть и родительным, в так называемом канцелярском стиле:

```
Дальний свет должен быть переключен на ближний согласно Пункта 19.2 ПДД.
```

[Грамота](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82&mode=spravka#:%7E:text=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%3A%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%20%E2%84%96,%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%3A%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%20%E2%84%96%202.)

[корпус](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClYqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKPbE%2Fpjtk4QLQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCKgooCiYKA3JlcRIfCh3RgdC%2B0LPQu9Cw0YHQvdC%2BINC%2F0YPQvdC60YLQsDAB)

Со стилистикой могут быть вопросы, а могут и не быть:

```
Одеваться надо согласно погоде (сезону)
```

Comment: Можно так писать и говорить. Ведь не запретишь! Но не нужно так писать и говорить. Об этом свидетельствует Нацкорпус. Ваш канцелярский стиль явно проигрывает как в худ. смысле, так и в административно-деловом: согласно пункта (4 примера), согласно пункту (51 пример). Свобода в языке и отклонения от общепринятого не могут быть самоцелью по образцу "я так вижу. " Оригинальные "специи" хороши как приправа, а иначе они утомляют.